# Can't get LG BH16NS40 to play Blu-Ray

Tags: windows-xp, video, dvd, media, blu-ray

I have an [LG BH16NS40](http://www.lg.com/us/data-storage/lg-BH16NS40)  internal DVD/Blu-Ray player, but I cannot get it to play Blu-Rays. I have updated it to the latest firmware.

It came with some "CyberLink" software but I uninstalled it because it was really obnoxious, running all the time, installing services, using the network connection and basically being CPU hogging spyware. Currently I am trying to use Aiseesoft Blu-Ray Player, a commercial software product, but it always reports "Invalid Blu-Ray File" when I try to load a disk.

Note that Media Player Classic DOES play regular DVDs using the same drive, so it can read and utilize the drive for regular DVDs, so the drive is definitely working.

OS is Windows XP (device properties show disks are being recognized by the player at a basic level:

[image: device properties]

These are the installed drivers:

[image: device drivers]

How can I further diagnose this problem?

Note that I have installed AnyMP4 now, for-pay software that looks practically identical to Aiseesoft, and it DOES work (albeit with occasional jerkiness). AnyMP4 did not install any new drivers so the "answers" below that say I "need a new driver" or different operating system are wrong.

The bottom line here is I need a better understanding of the media player programmatic flow chain so I can understand what is going on. I need an answer from somebody who knows what they are talking about and has, for example, programmed a DVD player. Advice like "upgrade your OS" or reboot your PC 15 times is not helpful. I am trying to understand under the hood.

Comment: Is this the original installation of Win XP (OEM)?  Is the blue ray player a device you added?  Did it originally work and then stopped or did you just install it and can't get it to work?  Did it work when the CyberLink software was installed?  If so, have you tried reinstalling it (or everything that you originally installed), to see if it works again?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, it worked with CyberLink on some blu-rays, but not all. I do not want to install PowerDVD software again. The OS is XP SP3.

Comment: It sounds like you're having problems finding a driver and software that work well with that player.  LG may have tested different software and found that PowerDVD worked, which is why they bundled it.  It might even have been a tweaked version.  The solution may require either trial and error with other software, or figuring out how to configure PowerDVD to work the way you want.  I would check with LG tech support to see what they recommend.

Comment: Try running the player as administrator.

Comment: Um, does your display support HDCP? Afaik the BluRay mafia requires the whole chain to support HDCP.

Comment: Note to those voting to close: this question is not a request for a product recommendation.  It is about how to get an existing device to function properly.  If a potential solution involves other software, that does not make it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP does not nativly support BluRay discs.  MS does not provide drivers.

It seems to me that when you uninstalled Cyberlink, you also uninstalled the necessary drivers.  It maybe the case that only certain BluRay players support certain BluRay drives on Windows XP.

I would suggest that you try a more modern operating system, that is currently supported.  MS has not produced any security fixes for just about a year, and has not released any 'new' software for Windows XP for over 5.

http://www.123copydvd.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/76/2/unable-to-recognize-or-load-bluray-discs-on-windows-xp

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/UDF-Reader

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1198284

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321640